# Enforce "click-to-play" in Chrome and Firefox domain-wide?

Tags: windows, domain, firefox, chrome, configuration

Is there any way to enforce the newish "Click-to-Play" setting for plugins (Java especially) for a domain of Windows systems?

I know I can go around to each of my 100 different users and set their Chrome and Firefox manually, but I obviously want to avoid that with either a GPO or a command-line script.

Comment: In Firefox (except version 14.0.1, due to a bug) you can change the default settings, or lock specific settings, using a mozilla.cfg file.  See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/933876

Comment: If you get it working, please post an answer for future viewers, preferably including the contents of mozilla.cfg.

Comment: After further manual testing with Firefox's implementation of Click-to-Play, we've decided not to go forward with this.  While Chrome's implementation worked well, with Firefox it just broke too many sites, with no way to "click" anywhere to "play" the plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 23 supports Click-to-Play through the DefaultPluginsSetting policy. The details at http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultPluginsSetting haven't been updated yet, but that policy can use value 3 to enforce click to play for plugins.